# Autocropping images to extract inner black border ROI using Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, imagemagick

I’ve been looking into OpenCV and Pillow (and ImageMagick outside of Python, especially [Fred's Image Magick Scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textdeskew/index.php)) to achieve the following:

Auto  identification of an inner black border in scanned Images and cropping of the images to this said border. Here is a blacked out example Image, the first is the "original" and the second one with a red highlight around the black border is what I am looking to achieve:

[image]
[image]

The problem is that the border is not on the outside of the images and the scans differ greatly in quality, meaning the border is never on the same spot and it’s not possible to crop by means of pixels.

Edit: I’m looking for a way to crop the image only keeping everything inside the black border (what is blurred right now)

I’m looking for help on how a) if it is possible to do such a cropping and b) how to do it preferably with Python.

Thanks!

Comment: what is this issue specifically, do you want to crop this border somehow?

Comment: See if you can de-skew the image, i.e. make it vertical with ImageMagick `magick input.png -deskew 40% result.png` If that works, you are now looking for long horizontal or vertical lines which are then pretty easy to locate with some morphology.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried it only using a Fred’s ImageMagick script which didn’t work, your command does and brings me one step closer, thanks!

Comment: @ImtinanAzhar yeah, I want to crop images like the one I posted automatically to what's inside the black border

Comment: Have you tried using Python/Opencv to do canny edge detection and then get the line intersections from Hough transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pretty simple way to do that in Imagemagick.

```
Get the center coordinates

Clone the image and do the following on the clone

Threshold the image so that the inside of the black lines is white. 

(If necessary use -connected-components to merge smaller black features into the white in the center)

Apply some morphology open to make sure that the black lines are continuous

Floodfill the image with red starting in the center

Convert non-red to black and red to white

Put the processed clone into the alpha channel of the input
```

Input:
[image]

```
center=$(convert img.jpg -format "%[fx:w/2],%[fx:h/2]\n" info:)

convert img.jpg \
\( +clone -auto-level -threshold 35% \
-morphology open disk:5 \
-fill red -draw "color $center floodfill" -alpha off \
-fill black +opaque red -fill white -opaque red \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

Here is Python Wand code that is the equivalent to the above:

```
#!/bin/python3.7

from wand.image import Image
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color
from wand.display import display

with Image(filename='black_rect.jpg') as img:
    with img.clone() as copied:
        copied.auto_level()
        copied.threshold(threshold=0.35)
        copied.morphology(method='open', kernel='disk:5')
        centx=round(0.5*copied.width)
        centy=round(0.5*copied.height)
        with Drawing() as draw:
            draw.fill_color='red'
            draw.color(x=centx, y=centy, paint_method='floodfill')
            draw(copied)
        copied.opaque_paint(target='red', fill='black', fuzz=0.0, invert=True)
        copied.opaque_paint(target='red', fill='white', fuzz=0.0, invert=False)
        display(copied)
        copied.alpha_channel = 'copy'
        img.composite(copied, left=0, top=0, operator='copy_alpha')
        img.format='png'
        display(img)
        img.save(filename='black_rect_interior.png')
```

*For OpenCV*, I would suggest that the following processing could be one way to do it. Sorry, I am not proficient with OpenCV

```
Threshold the image so that the inside of the black lines is white. 

Apply some morphology open to make sure that the black lines are continuous

Get the contours of the white regions.

Get the largest interior contour and fill the inside with white

Put that result into the alpha channel of the input
```

ADDITION:

For those interested, here is a longer method that would be conducive to perspective rectification. I do something similar to what nathancy has done, but in Imagemagick.

First, threshold the image and do morphology open to be sure the black lines are continuous.

Then do connected components to get the ID number of the largest white region

Then extract that region

```
id=$(convert img.jpg -auto-level -threshold 35% \
-morphology open disk:5 -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 8 null: | grep "gray(255)" | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/[:]*$//')
echo $id

convert img.jpg -auto-level -threshold 35% \
-morphology open disk:5 -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:keep=$id \
-connected-components 8 \
-alpha extract -morphology erode disk:5 \
region.png
```

[image]

Now do Canny edge detection and hough line transform. Here I save the canny image, the hough lines as red lines and the lines overlaid on the image and the line information, which is saved in the .mvg file.

```
convert region.png \
\( +clone -canny 0x1+10%+30% +write region_canny.png \
-background none -fill red -stroke red -strokewidth 2 \
-hough-lines 9x9+400 +write region_lines.png +write lines.mvg \) \
-compose over -composite region_hough.png

convert region_lines.png -alpha extract region_bw_lines.png

# Hough line transform: 9x9+400
viewbox 0 0 2000 2829
# x1,y1  x2,y2 # count angle distance
line 0,202.862 2000,272.704  # 763 92 824
line 204.881,0 106.09,2829  # 990 2 1156
line 1783.84,0 1685.05,2829  # 450 2 2734
line 0,2620.34 2000,2690.18  # 604 92 3240
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Next I use a script that I wrote to do corner detection. Here I use the Harris detector.

```
corners=$(corners -m harris -t 40 -d 5 -p yes region_bw_lines.png region_bw_lines_corners.png)
echo "$corners"

pt=1 coords=195.8,207.8
pt=2 coords=1772.8,262.8
pt=3 coords=111.5,2622.5
pt=4 coords=1688.5,2677.5
```

Next I extract and sort just the corners in clockwise fashion. The following is some code I wrote that I converted from [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/21/ordering-coordinates-clockwise-with-python-and-opencv/)

```
list=$(echo "$corners" | sed -n 's/^.*=\(.*\)$/\1/p' | tr "\n" " " | sed 's/[ ]*$//' )
echo "$list"
195.8,207.8 1772.8,262.8 111.5,2622.5 1688.5,2677.5

# sort on x
xlist=`echo "$list" | tr " " "\n" | sort -n -t "," -k1,1`
leftmost=`echo "$xlist" | head -n 2`
rightmost=`echo "$xlist" | tail -n +3`
rightmost1=`echo "$rightmost" | head -n 1`
rightmost2=`echo "$rightmost" | tail -n +2`
# sort leftmost on y
leftmost2=`echo "$leftmost" | sort -n -t "," -k2,2`
topleft=`echo "$leftmost2" | head -n 1`
btmleft=`echo "$leftmost2" | tail -n +2`
# get distance from topleft to rightmost1 and rightmost2; largest is bottom right
topleftx=`echo "$topleft" | cut -d, -f1`
toplefty=`echo "$topleft" | cut -d, -f2`
rightmost1x=`echo "$rightmost1" | cut -d, -f1`
rightmost1y=`echo "$rightmost1" | cut -d, -f2`
rightmost2x=`echo "$rightmost2" | cut -d, -f1`
rightmost2y=`echo "$rightmost2" | cut -d, -f2`
dist1=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:hypot(($topleftx-$rightmost1x),($toplefty-$rightmost1y))]" info:`
dist2=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:hypot(($topleftx-$rightmost2x),($toplefty-$rightmost2y))]" info:`
test=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$dist1>$dist2?1:0]" info:`
if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then
btmright=$rightmost1
topright=$rightmost2
else
btmright=$rightmost2
topright=$rightmost1
fi
sort_corners="$topleft $topright $btmright $btmleft"
echo $sort_corners

195.8,207.8 1772.8,262.8 1688.5,2677.5 111.5,2622.5
```

Finally, I use the corner coordinates to draw a white filled polygon on a black background and put that result into the alpha channel of the input image.

```
convert img.jpg \
\( +clone -fill black -colorize 100 \
-fill white -draw "polygon $sort_corners" \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting such a detailed answer and the Python Wand Code! Will check how this works for me after my vacation and mark the answer!

Comment: Since you blurred your actual text in the original, you may have to add the connected components processing to clean out the inside of the white area in the center of the rectangle in your actual image with the text not blurred.

Answer (score 2):

Alright long post incoming buckle up. Here's the strategy

- Convert image to grayscale and median blur
- Perform canny edge detection
- Perform morphological transformations to smooth image
- Dilate to enhance and connect contours
- Perform line detection and draw desired rectangle ROI onto mask
- Perform [Shi-Tomasi corner detection](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_shi_tomasi/py_shi_tomasi.html) to detect 4 corners
- Order corner points clockwise
- Draw corner points onto 2nd mask and find contour to obtain perfect ROI
- Perform perspective transform on ROI to obtain birds-eye view
- Rotate image to obtain final result

---

Canny edge detection

[image]

Next we perform morphological transformations to close gaps and smooth image (left). Then dilate to enhance contours (right)

[image]
[image]

From here, we perform line detection with `cv2.HoughLinesP()` with minimum line length and maximum line gap filters to obtain the large rectangular ROI. We draw this ROI onto a mask

```
minLineLength = 150
maxLineGap = 250
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dilate,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(mask,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),2)

mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=2)
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

[image]

Now we perform Shi-Tomasi corner detection with `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack()` to detect the four corner coordinates

```
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(mask,4,0.5,1000)

c_list = []
for corner in corners:
    x,y = corner.ravel()
    c_list.append([int(x), int(y)])
    cv2.circle(image,(x,y),40,(36,255,12),-1)
```

[image]

Unordered corner coordinates

> [[1690, 2693], [113, 2622], [1766, 269], [197, 212]]

From here, we reorder the four corner points clockwise by sorting the coordinates and rearranging them in `(top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left)` order. This step is important to obtain a top-down view of the ROI when we perform the perspective transform.

Ordered corner coordinates

> [[197,212],
>    [1766,269],
>    [1690,2693],
>    [113,2622]]

After reordering, we draw the points onto a 2nd mask to obtain the perfect ROI

[image]

We now perform a perspective transform on the ROI to obtain a top-down view of the image

[image]

Finally we rotate it `-90` degrees to obtain our desired result

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def rotate_image(image, angle):
    # Grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the center
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (w / 2, h / 2)

    # grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
    # angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
    # (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

    # Compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
    nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

    # Adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

    # Perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH))

def order_points_clockwise(pts):
    # sort the points based on their x-coordinates
    xSorted = pts[np.argsort(pts[:, 0]), :]

    # grab the left-most and right-most points from the sorted
    # x-roodinate points
    leftMost = xSorted[:2, :]
    rightMost = xSorted[2:, :]

    # now, sort the left-most coordinates according to their
    # y-coordinates so we can grab the top-left and bottom-left
    # points, respectively
    leftMost = leftMost[np.argsort(leftMost[:, 1]), :]
    (tl, bl) = leftMost

    # now, sort the right-most coordinates according to their
    # y-coordinates so we can grab the top-right and bottom-right
    # points, respectively
    rightMost = rightMost[np.argsort(rightMost[:, 1]), :]
    (tr, br) = rightMost

    # return the coordinates in top-left, top-right,
    # bottom-right, and bottom-left order
    return np.array([tl, tr, br, bl], dtype="int32")

def perspective_transform(image, corners):
    def order_corner_points(corners):
        # Separate corners into individual points
        # Index 0 - top-right
        #       1 - top-left
        #       2 - bottom-left
        #       3 - bottom-right
        corners = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners]
        top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r = corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3]
        return (top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l)

    # Order points in clockwise order
    ordered_corners = order_corner_points(corners)
    top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l = ordered_corners

    # Determine width of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (bottom right and bottom left) or (top right and top left) x-coordinates
    width_A = np.sqrt(((bottom_r[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_r[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    width_B = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - top_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - top_l[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_A), int(width_B))

    # Determine height of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (top right and bottom right) or (top left and bottom left) y-coordinates
    height_A = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - bottom_r[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - bottom_r[1]) ** 2))
    height_B = np.sqrt(((top_l[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_l[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_A), int(height_B))

    # Construct new points to obtain top-down view of image in 
    # top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r order
    dimensions = np.array([[0, 0], [width - 1, 0], [width - 1, height - 1], 
                    [0, height - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # Convert to Numpy format
    ordered_corners = np.array(ordered_corners, dtype="float32")

    # Find perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ordered_corners, dimensions)

    # Return the transformed image
    return cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (width, height))

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()

mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
clean_mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(image, 9)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 120, 255, 1)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
dilate = cv2.dilate(close, kernel, iterations=1)

minLineLength = 150
maxLineGap = 250
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dilate,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(mask,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),2)

mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=2)
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(mask,4,0.5,1000)

c_list = []
for corner in corners:
    x,y = corner.ravel()
    c_list.append([int(x), int(y)])
    cv2.circle(image,(x,y),40,(36,255,12),-1)

cv2.imwrite('corner_points.png', image)
corner_points = np.array([c_list[0], c_list[1], c_list[2], c_list[3]])
ordered_corner_points = order_points_clockwise(corner_points)
ordered_corner_points = np.array(ordered_corner_points).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(np.int32)

cv2.drawContours(clean_mask, [ordered_corner_points], -1, (255, 255, 255), 2)

cv2.imwrite('clean_mask.png', clean_mask)
clean_mask = cv2.cvtColor(clean_mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cnts = cv2.findContours(clean_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        transformed = perspective_transform(original, approx)

# Rotate image
result = rotate_image(transformed, -90)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imwrite('close.png', close)
cv2.imwrite('canny.png', canny)
cv2.imwrite('dilate.png', dilate)
cv2.imshow('clean_mask', clean_mask)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Edit: Another method**

Very similar to the above method but instead of using corner detection to find the ROI, we can extract the largest internal contour using contour area as a filter then use a mask to the get same results. The method is the same to get the perspective transform

[image]
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def rotate_image(image, angle):
    # Grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the center
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (w / 2, h / 2)

    # grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
    # angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
    # (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

    # Compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
    nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

    # Adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

    # Perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH))

def perspective_transform(image, corners):
    def order_corner_points(corners):
        # Separate corners into individual points
        # Index 0 - top-right
        #       1 - top-left
        #       2 - bottom-left
        #       3 - bottom-right
        corners = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners]
        top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r = corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3]
        return (top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l)

    # Order points in clockwise order
    ordered_corners = order_corner_points(corners)
    top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l = ordered_corners

    # Determine width of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (bottom right and bottom left) or (top right and top left) x-coordinates
    width_A = np.sqrt(((bottom_r[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_r[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    width_B = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - top_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - top_l[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_A), int(width_B))

    # Determine height of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (top right and bottom right) or (top left and bottom left) y-coordinates
    height_A = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - bottom_r[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - bottom_r[1]) ** 2))
    height_B = np.sqrt(((top_l[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_l[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_A), int(height_B))

    # Construct new points to obtain top-down view of image in 
    # top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r order
    dimensions = np.array([[0, 0], [width - 1, 0], [width - 1, height - 1], 
                    [0, height - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # Convert to Numpy format
    ordered_corners = np.array(ordered_corners, dtype="float32")

    # Find perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ordered_corners, dimensions)

    # Return the transformed image
    return cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (width, height))

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()

mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
clean_mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(image, 9)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 120, 255, 1)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
dilate = cv2.dilate(close, kernel, iterations=1)

minLineLength = 150
maxLineGap = 250
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dilate,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(mask,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),2)

mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=2)
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask)

cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]

for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(clean_mask, [c], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

clean_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(clean_mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=5)
result_no_transform = cv2.bitwise_and(clean_mask, image)

clean_mask = cv2.cvtColor(clean_mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cnts = cv2.findContours(clean_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        transformed = perspective_transform(original, approx)

result = rotate_image(transformed, -90)
cv2.imwrite('transformed.png', transformed)
cv2.imwrite('result_no_transform.png', result_no_transform)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
cv2.imwrite('clean_mask.png', clean_mask)
```

Comment: `@nathancy` Great answer! I started to approach it similarly in Imagemagick. But is it now simpler per my suggested methods. Don't you just have to threshold, use morphology to make the lines continuous. Then extract the contour of the largest interior white region and make that filled in to use as a mask to put into the alpha channel of the image? You could also just get the interior black region contour from your Hough line image. Sorry, I am no very proficient with OpenCV and am trying to learn.

Comment: Yes, its probably much simpler to use Imagemagick since there are many small details that need to be filtered out if OpenCV is used. Hmm yes that would be a better idea. Instead of finding the lines, just grabbing largest internal contour using contour area to filter then masking it would give the same ROI. Nice optimization, I guess I went the hard route

Comment: I was going the same route of canny, hough and corner detection in Imagemagick before I realized a much simpler solution was available. Nevertheless, your answer gives a lot of detail about such processing that will help me and I assume others learn more about OpenCV processing.

Comment: I do not see where in your code you get the rotation "angle" argument to put into cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(). Can you point that out?

Comment: It's at the very bottom `result = rotate_image(transformed, -90)`, essentially the argument is to rotate an image by some degree

Comment: Got it. Just overlooked. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for posting such a detailed answer! Will check how this works for me after my vacation and mark the answer 