# Image pre-processing issue of a parcel delivery slip before doing OCR

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ocr

I am interested in performing pre-processing of the **delivery slips** attached on the parcels. I have tried various OpenCV algorithms, but the performance is not upto the mark. I have tried the perspective transform approach and as well as hough line transform but the results are not satisfactory.

```
def four_point_transform(image, pts):
# obtain a consistent order of the points and unpack them
# individually
    rect = order_points(pts)
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = rect   
    widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))


    heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB)) 

    dst = np.array([
    [0, 0],
    [maxWidth - 1, 0],
    [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
    [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")

# compute the perspective transform matrix and then apply it
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))
```

The above code works well for a images on a flat surface but I need a generalised way for detecting/cropping my ROI in parcel images. This code has been referenced from this link, https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/ so this works well only for the kind of images shown in that blog. 
As the algorithm here relies on four point detection and corners detection, this does not suit my purpose because often the image on parcels have wrinkles and sometimes even if the slips are wrinkle free there are wrinkles in the packaging.
I have also tried working my way out following this link, [Autocropping images to extract inner black border ROI using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158869/autocropping-images-to-extract-inner-black-border-roi-using-python) but the border detection approach doesn't work. I have tried both the techniques mentioned in this thread of OpenCV.

Following are the images I tested this algorithm upon,
[Sample Delivery slip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxK0u.jpg)

I do feel that training a custom ROI detector using dlib or apply a custom trained object detection algorithm using Image.AI will work, but still I wish to know that whether training a custom model would be the best way out or is there any other possible way for this.